# Loop variable ends with a value one above expected

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

In VBA, running in Excel, I am running a basic loop that fills an array with values. The code is as below.

What I find curious, is the value of Counter starts at `0`, yet ends at `7`, rather than 6. I can note this when I'm looking in the Locals window and running the code step-by-step. It seems the value becomes `7` on its last instance of running 'Next'

Is this normal, or is there something I'm doing wrong?

It doesn't seem to change the outcome here, but if I'm using more complicated code, I want to be sure this is what I should be expecting.

```
Sub ArrayLoop()

    Dim myArray(6) As String
    Dim Counter As Integer

    For Counter = 0 To 6
        myArray(Counter) = Range("A1").Offset(Counter, 0).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: 0 is 1 and 6 would be 7. 0 is 1 in arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal: last iteration of the loop increments `Counter` to 7 and triggers the exit from loop

```
Counter = 7 ( > 6 )
```

There are algorithms based on the exit value of the `Counter`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayLoop()

    Dim myArray(6) As String
    Dim Counter As Integer

    For Counter = 0 To 6
        myArray(Counter) = Range("A1").Offset(Counter, 0).Value
    Next

    Do
        Debug.Print Counter     '---> 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
        Counter = Counter - 1
    Loop While Counter > 0

    Debug.Print Counter         '---> 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

remember that arrays are zero indexed. So technically the 7th time through the loop it should give you some sort of out of bounds error. Although there is technically nothing wrong with the way you are adding your values to the array.

Also remember that counter increments +1 each time after the loop is completed.

if you wanted it to only use 6 values you would have to change to

```
For Counter = 0 To 5
    myArray(Counter) = Range("A1").Offset(Counter, 0).Value
Next
```

this would start at 0 the first time through the loop add the value to the array with a 0 index, then increase the index each time +1 and increase the offset by 1 row each time through the loop. And it would only run the loop 6 times.